# Using fake_user agent, element not imported

Tags: python, web-scraping, user-agent

This is a simple crawling code written in Google Search.

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q=ipad+"apple"+intext:apple&hl=en&rlz=&start=10'
driver.get(url)
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div/div')
title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/a/h3')

print(len(items))
print(len(title))

for item in items:
    title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div/div/div/a/h3').text
    print(title)
```

output, it works

[image]

Added fake_user agent as follows,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'c:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q=ipad+"apple"+intext:apple&hl=en&rlz=&start=10'
driver.get(url)
items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div/div')
title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/a/h3')

print(len(items))
print(len(title))

for item in items:
    title = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//div/div/div/a/h3').text
    print(title)
```

output

[image]

After adding the fake_user agent code, why can't I get results from the same code?

Comment: Have you tried using regular useragent. Isn't this cuz of "headless"?

Comment: @Xitiz whether it has headless or not, it works for my working original code, which means  adding fake user-agent one didn't work. Also, if I use regular useragent, it gets elements correctly.